# Executing all Methods pointed to by a Template Parameter Pack

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, pointer-to-member, template-function

1. Can I make a template parameter pack of method (=member function) pointers?
2. If yes, is it possible to make a (template) function that executes all methods in its template parameter pack?

Simplifications:

- The order of execution of the pointed methods does not matter.
- All method pointers have the same signature (e.g. return `bool`, have the same base class, take no arguments)

Comment: Yes, and yes. Did you try ? :)

Comment: @Quentin: Yes, I did, without success so far. Could you show me an example? I have not found an example on the web yet.

Comment: Can you show one of your try? If you don't show your attempt, we can't show where is your error.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class T, class...Ms>
void run_all(T* t, Ms&&... ms) {
  using discard=int[];
  (void)discard{0,(void(
    (t->*ms)()
  ),0)...};
}
```

Use:

```
struct foo {
  bool t1() { return true; }
  bool t2() const { return false; }
};
int main() {
  foo f;
  run_all(&f, &foo::t1, &foo::t2);
}
```

`run_all` is obtuse, but that is because we don't have C++17.

```
template<class T, class...Ms>
void run_all(T* t, Ms&&... ms) {
  ((void)((t->*ms)()),...);
}
```

which is a bit simpler, or even:

```
template<class T, class...Ms>
void run_all(T* t, Ms&&... ms) {
  ((t->*ms)(),...);
}
```

which relies on `t->*ms` returning a sane type.

We could also rely on the fact that `ms` returns bool and do:

```
template<class T, class...Ms>
void run_all(T* t, Ms&&... ms) {
  (void)std::initializer_list<bool>{(t->*ms)()...};
}
```

or

```
template<class T, class...Ms>
void run_all(T* t, Ms&&... ms) {
  using discard=bool[];
  (void)discard{false,(t->*ms)()...};
}
```

Note that all of these execute their methods *in order* and support passing 0 methods.

Some of the above `void` casts are to block warnings for unused values.

Others are there to deal with the possibility that a call returns a type that overloads `operator,`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, the templates are not taking parameter packs of method pointers.

Comment: @ManuelAtWork I am passing method pointers.  The type of those arguments is thus method pointers.  So they are parameter packs of ... method pointers.  What, exactly, do you mean by they are not parameter packs of method pointers?  You mean *other* types could possibly be accepted?  True, but it will only compile if they have overridden `->*`, in which case why do you care?

Comment: All your template Parameter packs begin with ```class...```, which makes then **type** parameter packs. The C++ standard also allows non-type template parameters like integers or pointers. You are passing method pointers, but not as template parameters but as function parameters. I am sorry, if my question was ambiguous.

Comment: @ManuelAtWork Oh, that is what you mean.  This is why you want to post actual code attempts in questions; I had no clue you wanted to pass them as non-type template parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyClass {

  /* The methods to be executed: */

  bool func_1() const { /* ... */ }
  bool func_2() const { /* ... */ }
  // ...


  /* The parameter pack expansion: */

  typedef bool (MyClass::*FuncPtr)() const;

  template<class T = void>
  void Expand() const {}  // Termination version.

  template<FuncPtr ptr, FuncPtr ... Args>
  void Expand() const {
    (this->*ptr)();
    Expand<Args...>();
  }


  /* The function that calls them all: */

  void RunAll() const {
    Expand< 
      &MyClass::func_1, // <-- input to parameter pack
      &MyClass::func_2
    >();
  }

};
```

---

Alternate version without recursion:

```
class MyClass {

  /* The methods to be executed: */

  bool func_1() const { /* ... */ }
  bool func_2() const { /* ... */ }
  // ...


  /* The parameter pack expansion: */

  typedef bool (MyClass::*FuncPtr)() const;

  template<typename ... T> void ignore(T && ...) {}

  template<FuncPtr ... Args> 
  void Expand() const {
    ignore( ((this->*Args)(),0) ... );
  }

  /* The function that calls them all: */

  void RunAll() const {
    Expand< 
      &MyClass::func_1, // <-- input to parameter pack
      &MyClass::func_2
    >();
  }

};
```

(contribution from @Yakk)

Comment: Steal the pack expansions from my answer to get rid of the zero-arg termination version and remove recursion.  The first one, the one with `disard`, replace `t` with `this` and `ms` with `ptrs`, and take `template<FuncPtr...ptrs>`

Comment: @Yakk So I did. Thank you for the recursion-free approach!

Comment: Symbols starting with double underscore are reserved by the implementation.  Do not mimic standard/system header file style; they are permitted and in some cases must use that style.

Comment: @Yakk: I have found an even shorter version using the ```ignore``` function template. It silences the "unused variable" warnings automatically.

Comment: the downside is you lose ordering guarantees.  The upside is you can remove the `,0`